# Json_decode limit

Tags: php, json

I'm using `json_decode()` but for some reason it trims the last digits, example:

```
$test = '[{"Endereco_POI":"","UF":"SP","IBGE_N":"3509502","IBGE":"350950","Municipio":"CAMPINAS","Bairro":"","CEP":"1305883","Numero":"","X":-47.17788692505713,"Y":-22.918751685387484,"Prioridade":6,"Score":100.0,"Erro":347.59,"EnderecoEncontrado":"1305883, CAMPINAS SP"}]';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($test, TRUE));
echo "</pre>";
```

the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Endereco_POI] => 
            [UF] => SP
            [IBGE_N] => 3509502
            [IBGE] => 350950
            [Municipio] => CAMPINAS
            [Bairro] => 
            [CEP] => 1305883
            [Numero] => 
            [X] => -47.177886925057
            [Y] => -22.918751685387
            [Prioridade] => 6
            [Score] => 100
            [Erro] => 347.59
            [EnderecoEncontrado] => 1305883, CAMPINAS SP
        )

)
```

so insted of -47.17788692505713 it outputs -47.177886925057.

Whats the reason for that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Float precision probably.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the *php.ini* file setting for:

> precision

By default it is set to 14. From the manual [Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision):

> The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.

Comment: there you go... raised the number it worked just fine, thanks

Comment: Great. Please select this as the answer to your problem please.

Answer (score 1):

You have more decimal places than PHP supports:

```
php > $y = -22.918751685387484;
php > echo $y;
-22.918751685387
```

If you need those trailing digits, then the float values have to encoded as strings inside the JSON:

```
php > $y = "-22.918751685387484";
php > echo $y;
-22.918751685387484
```